# How to find out if local account is linked with Microsoft Live account?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, onedrive

In my win-store application I want to give use access to skydrive files and ability to manage multiple accounts.

There can be two situation:

1. Local account is linked with Microsoft Account. In this case I can use Live SDK and user doesn't need to write password to login into the SkyDrive.
2. Local account isn't linked with Microsoft Account. In this case I can use Live SDK too and user must write password to login into the SkyDrive - but currently I have no ability to manage multiple accounts.

What I want:

Find out if local account is linked with Microsoft Live account.

1. If linked, I show user a popup, where user can choose which account to use - current without need to enter password or some another account.
2. If not linked, I just use my implementation of SkyDrive client and user goes to write password manually.

How can this be done? How I can find out if local account is linked with Microsoft Live account?

Unfortunately, Google doesn't helped.

Comment: I would assume (I haven't verified) that such a thing would be impossible in the Windows Runtime sandbox, for privacy/security reasons. I don't think I would want spyware games to call such an API...

Comment: @KrisVandermotten What I want - not to know to which microsoft live account. I just want true/false: linked or not. But it seems that your assumption is true, from my experience of googling.